# Living on the edge: can I change a constant string in a deployed asp.net website page dll?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, dll

*(Unfortunately, this question is about a non-recommended practice. While I appreciate advise against doing what I request here, I know it isn't good practice anyway, but every now and then we just have to and open our trick bag ;-))*

In a situation where we accidentally published an asp.net website, without updatability, with one wrong URL, we'd like to just open that DLL and change the URL, to prevent waiting another week for the next publish opportunity.

In oldish native DLLs I knew how to change resources, but how would I attempt this with .NET DLLs? And is there an *easy* way, or only a hackerish one (I know of `ildasm` and `ilasm`)?

If it matters, the string is a literal inside an event handler.

Comment: If you've got access to the DLL to be able to make changes to it, why can't you just republish? If it's just procedure, can't you explain it's safer to republish than to attempt a hacky fix with potentially unknown consequence? In a way, isn't changing the DLL just republishing it anyway, in a manner of speaking?

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with bgs264 on this one.  (I know, I read your disclaimer at the start of the question.)  Editing the DLL, from the perspective of the runtime, is no different from replacing it.  The file is changed, it has to be re-loaded.  (Someone like Jon Skeet may be able to shed more light on the internals of that.)  Re-building the DLL properly and swapping it out is safer and accomplishes, from the perspective of the runtime, the same thing.

Comment: @David / @bgs264: I agree, but the pages have not been published with single-page assemblies and/or strong naming, thus just replacing will not work. Yes, changing *anything* in the bin directory will reload the web site. But our application deployment is a bit more involved than just that, and having the website shortly on hold while reloading (takes 1 minute) is better than having a maintenance screen on the website (takes typically an hour and can only be done Sunday's, 4AM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few approaches worth considering:

- Reflector, with the [ReflexIL plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reflexil/), is capable of editing the IL of a compiled assembly. If you are using code signing, however, you may have a headache tweaking a signed assembly.
- Robocopy is a useful tool for publishing web sites that may have only minor changes. Robocopy is capable of copying only files that have been modified. I have a few websites that take 8+ hours to publish raw, but take fewer than 10 minutes to publish changes via robocopy (and those 10 minutes are mostly non-disruptive to the web site).

Comment: Forgot about your answer for a long time, sorry about that. Your tips are good, but I ended up changing our procedure to named dlls, which made it easier to do individual updates.